# Custom View that takes & delete a Camera Picture

Tags: android, view, camera

Hi I am trying to create a Custom View that takes as well as deletes a picture and looks like the following:

[image]

Following operations a view can perform:

- Take a picture (by clicking on the No Image Available sign)   -- works
- Delete a picture  (by clicking on the red cross) -- works
- Preview a picture

How do I create a listener to find out when the image has been taken by the camera? The location of the image that needs to be taken is known before.

```
public class artooPicture extends RelativeLayout {

    ImageView preview, delete;
    String value = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/99006796"
            + "_" + ".jpg", suffix;
    boolean clicked = false;

    public artooPicture(Context context) {
        this(context, null);

    }

    public artooPicture(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);

    }

    public artooPicture(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.picture,
                this, true);

        delete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.scan_delete);
        preview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.scan_preview);

        File f = new File(value);
        if (f.exists()) {
            clicked = true;
            preview.setImageDrawable(BitmapDrawable.createFromPath(value));

        } else {

        }

        delete.setOnClickListener(deleteListener);
        preview.setOnClickListener(previewListener);
    }

    View.OnClickListener deleteListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(clicked){
                File f = new File(value);
                f.delete();
                preview.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
            }

            clicked = false;
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener previewListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(value)));
            getContext().startActivity(i);

        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using Threads. Does anyone have a better solution?

```
View.OnClickListener previewListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!clicked) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri
                        .fromFile(new File(value)));
                getContext().startActivity(i);

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        File f;
                        do {
                            f = new File(value);
                        } while (!f.exists());
                        if (f.exists()) {
                            preview.setImageDrawable(BitmapDrawable
                                    .createFromPath(value));
                            clicked = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
                t.run();

            } else {
                Dialog d = new Dialog(getContext());
                ImageView iv = new ImageView(getContext());
                iv.setImageDrawable(BitmapDrawable.createFromPath(value));              
                d.setContentView(iv);
                d.setCancelable(true);
                d.show();
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `startActivityForResult()` and set the preview in your

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
     Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
     ImageView image = new ImageView(this.getApplicationContext());
     image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}
```

method?

Comment: I am creating a view that can be embedded anywhere. From a View you can start an activity but not an activityForResult